# Vaadin panel is shown although set to invisible

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin application and have the following code

```
Panel thePanel = new Panel("MainPanel");
HorizontalLayout panelContent = new HorizontalLayout();
panelContent.setSpacing(true);
panelContent.setMargin(true);
panelContent.setWidth("100%");
Label description = new Label("Description");
panelContent.addComponent(description);
panelContent.setVisible(false);
thePanel.addClickListener((e) -> panelContent.setVisible(! panelContent.isVisible()));
thePanel.setContent(panelContent);
```

this panel is added to a VerticalLayout and this is set as tab for a tab sheet.

My problem is the panels are visible, when the page is loaded.

[image]
only when clicking on one of it works expected
[image]

why is the latter not shown at the beginning ?

Thanks

Comment: just to prevent any confusion: you click two times on each panel to get the result in the second image? your first click shows the labels there as expected, right?

Comment: When the pages loaded, it shows the first image. When I click on a panel, this panel is visible and the description is shown, all other panels are shown as in the second image... sorry cut the second picture wrong, not showing the clicked panel

Comment: Latest Vaadin? Seems to be a layouting bug.

Comment: I'm using Vaadin 7.6.6

Comment: Any chance we could get a fully functional stripped down sample (aka [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) which reproduces just this issue? Also please use @username when replying to comments so the person gets notified.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and wasn't successful. I got the second screen shot from the beginning without clicks. You should really make a SSCCE to get help.

Comment: argh - I cannot reproduce it either... not sure what has changed - and now it always shows the expected behaviour

Comment: Maybe you upgraded Vaadin and did not recompile widget set (if add-ons are present)?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich you are probably right - thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people from the comments, I can also not reproduce it anymore. It now shows the expected behaviour